# The elements of HBox are working wrong

Tags: javafx, view, label, element, hbox

When money label (into the moneyBox) has no more than 5 digits everything is fine, but when money is increasing the design is going to be messy. How can I fix it?

```
    StackPane bottom = new StackPane();
    VBox vboxBottom = new VBox();
    HBox hboxBottomElements = new HBox(15);
    HBox hboxBottomMain = new HBox(0);

    hboxBottomElements.getChildren().addAll(visaLabel, separator2, adLabel, separator3, governRelationStatus, separator4, christianityLabel);
    hboxBottomElements.setPadding(new Insets(5));

    vboxBottom.getChildren().addAll(season, separator1, hboxBottomElements);
    vboxBottom.setPadding(new Insets(30,0,0,0));

    bottom.getChildren().addAll(vboxBottom, next);
    StackPane.setAlignment(next, Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    StackPane.setMargin(next, new Insets(0,0,0,999));
    hboxBottomMain.getChildren().addAll(moneyBox, bottom);

    layout.setBottom(hboxBottomMain);
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiZVC.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaqtl.jpg)

Comment: Using `false` for the `wrapText` property should result in a ellipsis instead of a line break. I've no idea, if this is the desired behavior since you do not describe the desired behavior... Also note that it's hard to get the scene structure from code especially, if half of the nodes are created/declared somewhere outside the code snippet. Consider creating a fxml file creating the necessary node structure to reproduce the problem...

Comment: Here is the solution :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599738/java-fx-out-of-the-window-screen?noredirect=1#comment72330340_42599738

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is change the way money is displayed when it gets that large.

You have `10,000,000$` you are trying to display. You may be able to change that to say `10m$` where `M` is million. Then, when you get to `1,000m`, you could change it to `1b`, etc..

I'm not sure how you get this number, but it can be achieved by some simple arithmatic. i.e..

```
if(money > 9,999,999){
    displayMoney = money/1,000,000.00;
    displayMoneyString = displayMoney + "m$";
}
```

So something like that to remove some unneccessary or large numbers,

Hope this helps.