# Java FX out of the window screen

Tags: button, javafx, menu, hbox

I wanna it will be okay when the number variables is changed, but when the are increased the button goes out from the window. How to fix it? Also how to put the bar down to the level of "10$", so they will be in the same row?

Before :
[image: Before]

After :
[image: After]

Here is my code :

```
VBox vboxBottom = new VBox();
HBox hboxBottomElements = new HBox(15);
HBox hboxBottomMain = new HBox(0);

Region region = new Region();
region.setPrefWidth(500);

hboxBottomElements.getChildren().addAll(visaLabel, separator2, adLabel, separator3, governRelationStatus, separator4, region, next);
hboxBottomElements.setPadding(new Insets(5));

vboxBottom.getChildren().addAll(separator1, new Group(hboxBottomElements));

vboxBottom.setPadding(new Insets(3));

hboxBottomMain.getChildren().addAll(new Group(moneyBox), vboxBottom);
hboxBottomMain.setPadding(new Insets(3));
layout.setBottom(hboxBottomMain);
```

Comment: If you want the button to be at the right edge of the window, use an anchor pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a `Group` here

```
vboxBottom.getChildren().addAll(separator1, new Group(hboxBottomElements));
```

you're creating a layout structure that resizes `hboxBottomElements` to it's prefered size independent of the space available.
`HBox` simply moves elements out the right side of it's bounds, if the space available does not suffice. This means if the `Group` containing `moneyBox` grows, the `Button` is moved out of the `HBox`...

The following simpler example demonstrates the behavior:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Do something");
    HBox.setHgrow(btn, Priority.NEVER);
    btn.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    Region filler = new Region();
    filler.setPrefWidth(100);
    HBox.setHgrow(filler, Priority.ALWAYS);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200, 50);
    HBox hBox = new HBox(rect, filler, btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This will resize `filler` to make the `HBox` fit the window.

Now replace

```
Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);
```

with

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(hBox));
```

and the `Button` will be moved out of the window...